# Writing Java predicate to compare a list against another

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to write a Java lambda expression with streams to do what the following code is doing. Given a *List of Person* and a *List of DateFilter*, remove any person from the persons list whose birthdate matches any of the dates within a range in the DateFilter list.

```
    List<Person> people = getPerson();
    List<DateFilter> dateFilters = getDateFilters();        
    List<Person> filteredPersons = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Person p : people){
        boolean isWithinRange = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < dateFilters.size() && !isWithinRange; i++){
            DateFilter dateFilter = dateFilters.get(i);
            if(numOfDaysBetween(p.getBirthDate(),dateFilter.getDate())  < dateFilter.getDiffRange()){
                isWithinRange = true;
            }
        }
        if(!isWithinRange){
            filteredPersons.add(p);
        }
    }
```

Is there a simplified way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: He showed his code already. It is working, but he is asking how to simplify it. He want to rewrite this code using Java 8 streams/lambda. Right, @user1309197?

Comment: @spirit: No, he showed his code without streams.  He hasn't shown his attempt with streams.

Comment: yes, maybe because he doesn't know how to do it =) that's why he asking for help, I guess =))

Comment: @spirit: That would be a perfectly valid answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirement :

> Given a List of Person and a List of DateFilter, remove any person
>   from the persons list whose birthdate matches any of the dates withing
>   a range in the DateFilter list.

It sounds like mutability of your original `people` list is not a problem. Considering this, you can simplify your code with the `removeIf` function which also takes a `Predicate` and get rid of some boilerplate code + avoid the creation of a new `List` :

```
people.removeIf(person -> dateFilters.stream()
    .noneMatch(f -> numOfDaysBetween(person.getBirthDate(), f.getDate()) < f.getDiffRange()));
```

Then your `people` list will be cleaned from any `Person` that did not match the predicate.

Comment: As much as I'd advise against mutability in most situations, this is a very good answer if that is what you want.  Though that's not what the original code did.

Comment: Beautiful solution ! I took @MarkPeters suggestion and added includes() method to DateFilter class to make it even cleaner. I will mark it as correct answer. I am just trying to see if I can write a separate method to return this filter instead of writing inline filter.

Comment: @user1309197 Sure you can :

 `Predicate<Person> isInvalidPerson = person -> dateFilters.stream()
    .noneMatch(f -> numOfDaysBetween(person.getBirthDate(), f.getDate()) < f.getDiffRange())`

Then you can use `people.removeIf(isInvalidPerson);`

Answer (score 3):

You have two stream operations; one to filter `people`, and one to create the predicate against all of your `DateFilter`s:

```
List<Person> matchingPeople = people.stream()
    .filter(p -> dateFilters.stream()
        .anyMatch(df -> 
           numOfDaysBetween(p.getBirthDate(), df.getDate())  < df.getDiffRange()
        )
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would encourage you to add a method to your `DateFilter` class so that you can do something like this though:

```
dateFilters.stream().anyMatch(df -> df.includes(p.getBirthDate()))
```

The arithmetic for the date match is better suited to the `DateFilter` class.